# Disable <a> after click on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following problem. The code below gives me a link to perform the delete of a row in my table.

This link invokes a confirm so the user confirm or not the delete.

What I want to do is after the confirm the `<a>` becomes disabled. How can I do it?

```
<a class="actionIcon" onclick="if (confirm('Tem a certeza que quer fechar o ticket \&quot;You can \&quot;?')) { var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'post'; f.action = this.href;var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); m.setAttribute('name', 'sf_method'); m.setAttribute('value', 'delete'); f.appendChild(m);var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); m.setAttribute('name', '_csrf_token'); m.setAttribute('value', 'cd78fd1b6aa79fa78c338a94951912f2'); f.appendChild(m);f.submit(); };return false;" href="/qdPM/index.php/tickets/delete/id/4162/projects_id/71/redirect_to/ticketsList"><img title="Fechar" class="iconDelete"></a>
```

Comment: You're already manipulating the form, so what have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: My goodness, why on Earth is that all INLINE? make a function, call it, and add a class to disable the link!  Edit: My scroller just commited suicide.

Comment: lol, if you already use onClick... then remove the a tag, put in on another element, onClick check a var, after the confirm put the var with different value et voilà, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, you can simply add: `this.onclick = function() {return false;}` to your event handler.

But as a more robust solution, you *really, really, **really*** should NOT use inline event handlers, especially not for something so complex.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
<a class="actionIcon" id="action"><img title="Fechar" href="/qdPM/index.php/tickets/delete/id/4162/projects_id/71/redirect_to/ticketsList" class="iconDelete"></a>

$(function()
{
    $("#action").click(function()
    {
        if (confirm('Tem a certeza que quer fechar o ticket \&quot;You can \&quot;?')) 
        { 
          var f = document.createElement('form'); 
          f.style.display = 'none'; 
          this.parentNode.appendChild(f);
          f.method = 'post'; 
          f.action = this.href;
          var m = document.createElement('input');
          m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
          m.setAttribute('name', 'sf_method'); 
          m.setAttribute('value', 'delete'); 
          f.appendChild(m);
          var m = document.createElement('input'); 
          m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
          m.setAttribute('name', '_csrf_token'); 
          m.setAttribute('value', 'cd78fd1b6aa79fa78c338a94951912f2'); 
          f.appendChild(m);
          f.submit(); 
        }

        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - CSS > Create a class with disabled;

```
a.ActiveAnchor { 
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
 }
```

2- Change the class with jQUERY;

```
$( "#AchorID" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```